# Xcode 9: UITextField clipping text inside UIStackView accompanied by a UILabel

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uilabel, uistackview

UITextField clipping text inside UIStackView accompanied by a UILabel.

In Xcode it looks like this:

[image]

Running on phone/simulator( vertical alignment is off, bit above the centre):

[image]

Structure:

[image]

**Stack view:**

Alignment: Fill

Distribution: Fill Equally

Height Set to 40

Horizontally/Vertically aligned in centre

Left/Right Margins set to 10 to super view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a bug in Xcode, have a look at this review from App Store...

[image]